# Customize verification email screen using auth0

Tags: auth0

Anyone can help me to customize verificaiton email screen with auth0?
I can't find out the way to customize it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the email templates in the dashboard section "Branding > Email templates". You can check the [doc page about it](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/email/email-templates). However, "any customizations made to this email template will NOT take effect until a Custom Email Provider is configured". You can read that on a warning on the dashboard if a custom Email provider is not configured.

[image: Warning at Email templates with Auth0 Email Provider configured]